# Протокол передачи данных поверх существующего UDP/TCP

Tags: java, tcp, udp, передача-данных, протоколы

Интересует возможность написания своего собственного протокола передачи данных и "включении" его в рабочий ход вещей. То есть сделать так, чтобы данные, которые приходят к нам посредством UDP/TCP пакетов, проходили еще некоторый "фильтр" в виде моего протокола.

Как можно его "вживить" в хорошо отлаженную и работающую систему модели ОСИ? Чтобы был еще один уровень, скажем. Реально ли это сделать? Если да, то куда смотреть, как реализовать?

Интересна реализация на Java. Как создать такой уровень и плюс минус настроить - понятие имеется. Не понимаю пока, как его внедрить в систему.

**UPD**: Так же возможна собственная реализация протокола UDP и "подмена интересов", то есть использование моего протокола вместо имеющегося. Тут возникает вопрос: а куда зашиты все эти протоколы и уровни модели ОСИ и как идет обработка нолей и единиц, которые приходят к нам на компьютер через wi-fi или rj-45.

Comment: Что значит вживить? Вы хотите что бы другая программа которая работает через TCP заработала через ваш протокол?

Comment: `iptables ... -j NFQUEUE`, например.

Comment: @zergatul, я хочу, чтобы весь интернет трафик работал через мой протокол. Любое приложение, которое запускается на компьютере и использует интернет получает данные через сеть (сетевую карту) и дальше уровни модели их декодируют и доводят до приложения. Я хочу добавить ещё один уровень либо заменить на транспортном уровне протокол UDP, например, на свой, если не получится добавить ещё один уровень-обработчик.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, а подробнее? Что мне это даст?

Comment: Засылку подпадающих под правило пакетов процессу-обработчику, который, возможно, после обработки отправит, возможно изменённые, пакеты обратно в очередь.